What is the difference between AWS Textract DetectDocumentText and AnalyzeDocument functions?
I am doing some research into AWS Textract functionality. I see that there are two main ways to get information from PDF files (synchronously): DetectDocumentText and AnalyzeDocument. I have been trying to understand the difference between the two functions but I can't seem to find concrete information.
Based on API documentation DetectDocumentText returns the text detected in a document, while AnalyzeDocument analyzes documents and forms for relationships among detected text. However, I see that DetectDocumentText returns relationships so this is where I am getting confused about the difference between the two API calls.
DetectDocumentText returns:

The lines and words of detected text
The relationships between the lines and words of detected text
The page that the detected text appears on
The location of the lines and words of text on the document page

Some questions:

Does this mean that DetectDocumentText need to be called before AnalyzeDocument so that the text can be detected and then we call AnalyzeDocument to understand the relationships between the text?
Should DetectDocumentText only be used when there aren't forms in the data?
Is there a benefit to using DetectDocumentText vs AnalyzeDocument?

Any help to understand the two functions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!


However, I see that DetectDocumentText returns relationships so this is where I am getting confused about the difference between the two API calls.

The result of a Textract call is always going to be a graph structure: specifically a forest, with each page being the root of the tree, and all the detections as nodes descending from there. Of course, all graphs have nodes and edges. However, the important part here is that Textract gives you JSON that only contains a flat list of nodes. The relationships field is what contains those edges: it's a list of IDs for the detections that neighbor the current node. This is the same no matter which Textract API call you make.

Based on API documentation DetectDocumentText returns the text detected in a document

This isn't actually 100% true, based on what I just described. You're not just getting the raw text as a long string — you're getting that graph, where each node contains a whole bunch of information about its geometry on the page, its hierarchy within the document, and the confidence level for that particular detection. It's very granular, like one or two words, so no matter what you use there's some degree of reconstruction in your application that needs to be done to get the full text of the document. Think about a document with complex arrangements of columns and paragraph — like the front page of a newspaper for instance. Textract doesn't know how to reassemble the reading order of that text on its own (i.e. the spatial index), so it makes no assumptions on your behalf.

Should DetectDocumentText only be used when there aren't forms in the data?

Not necessarily, DetectDocumentText can be used if you don't need the forms to be detected. (or tables, or queries, etc). AnalyzeDocument will give you really nice data structures in that graph that highlight those document features specifically, whereas DetectDocumentText will have those features appear as LINEs and WORDs, indistinguishable from other text on the page.

Does this mean that DetectDocumentText need to be called before AnalyzeDocument so that the text can be detected and then we call AnalyzeDocument to understand the relationships between the text?

Absolutely not. AnalyzeDocument will give you everything you get from DetectDocumentText plus extra — including all the text in the document. Typically you should know whether you need those document features like tables and forms in advance, depending on your use case. But it definitely doesn't require two API calls.

Is there a benefit to using DetectDocumentText vs AnalyzeDocument?

Because DetectDocumentText isn't as full-featured, I think it's cheaper per API call.

Technically because each document yields a directed acyclic graph from Textract, I suppose the real description is actually polytree and polyforest. But I'm leaving it as is for simplicity's sake.

DetectDocumentText is sync.
AnalyzeDocument not.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
